# Jackson Data Binding: Reading into existing object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a way I can do something like the following using Jackson Data Binding? Obviously this won't compile but for example (psuedoCode):

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
String json = "{ name: "hello" }";
ObjectMapper.readValue(json, myObject);
myObject.getName() -> returns "hello";
```

Basically what I want to do is write a string data into an existing object and not pass Jackson data binding a class like `objectMapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson provides [`ObjectMapper#readerForUpdating(Object)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForUpdating%28java.lang.Object%29) which gives you an [`ObjectReader`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html) you can use to fill in the blanks.